# turning strings to ints and getting the total value by addition

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I have a for loop which iterates through an array of UI.text elements (total of 6), and randomly assigns a number to each by converting this number into a string. I'm trying to - either before or after their transformation - collect the total value of these 6 numbers when added together. i.e. 6+1+2+3+4+1 = 17. The code below is wrong as it produces a '0' in the console - I have noticed that it gives a total object value on the right hand side which always equals the correct sum-total, however this is not seemingly useful.
Is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < blueHex1CardNumbers.Length; i++)
    {
        int j = Random.Range(1, 6);
        string myString = j.ToString();

        blueHex1CardNumbers[i].text = myString;


        int numbers = System.Int32.Parse(blueHex1CardNumbers[i].text);
        int[] total = new int[numbers]; //This is where i think the problem lies
        for(int l = 0; l < total.Length; l++)
        {
            int final = total.Sum ();
            Debug.Log(final);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
// Add this up here
int totals = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < blueHex1CardNumbers.Length; i++)
{
    int j = Random.Range(1, 6);
    // increment it as you go
    totals += j;

    string myString = j.ToString();
    blueHex1CardNumbers[i] = myString;
}

// use your totals here
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you!! I had a feeling it should be simpler!

Comment: Glad I could help. Since it seems you're on the path on learning, here's the best advice I can give you. Keep it simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var random = new Random();
var ints = Enumerable.Repeat(0, blueHex1CardNumbers.Length)
                     .Select(_ => random.Next(1, 6))
                     .ToArray(); // six random ints
var strings = ints.Select(n => n.ToString());
var total = ints.Sum();
var i = 0;
foreach (var s in strings)
    blueHex1CardNumbers[i++].Text = s;
```